# Fixed pixel-size WinForm Custom control inside WPF full screen application

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-resolution, resolution-independence, windowsformshost

I try to insert a Winform custom control inside WindowsFormHost. This custom control only works in a fixed height & width.

I try to specify the width & height for this custom control & the WindowsFormHost, but since WPF size is resolution-independent, the control got scaled and ruined the position.

Is there any way I can do to force the size of this custom control in pixel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate the `WindowsFormHost` within a [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), cause with it you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to its area.